# Exceptions with Unicode what()

Tags: c++, c++11

Or, "how do Russians throw exceptions?"

The definition of std::exception is:

```
namespace std {
  class exception {
  public:
    exception() throw();
    exception(const exception&) throw();
    exception& operator=(const exception&) throw();
    virtual ~exception() throw();
    virtual const char* what() const throw();
  };
}
```

A [popular school of thought](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/exceptions.html#faq-17.12) for designing exception hierarchies is to derive from std::exception:

> Generally, it's best to throw objects,
> not built-ins. If possible, you should
> throw instances of classes that derive
> (ultimately) from the std::exception
> class. By making your exception class
> inherit (ultimately) from the standard
> exception base-class, you are making
> life easier for your users (they have
> the option of catching most things via
> std::exception), plus you are probably
> providing them with more information
> (such as the fact that your particular
> exception might be a refinement of
> std::runtime_error or whatever).

But in the face of Unicode, it seems to be impossible to design an exception hierarchy that achieves both of the following:

- Derives ultimately from std::exception for ease of use at the catch site
- Provides Unicode compatibility so that diagnostics are not sliced or gibberish

Coming up with an exception class that can be constructed with Unicode strings is simple enough.  But the standard dictates that what() must return a const char*, so at some point the input strings must be converted to ASCII.  Whether that is done at construction time or when what() is called (if the source string uses characters not representable by 7-bit ASCII), it might be impossible to format the message without loss of fidelity.

How do you design an exception hierarchy that combines the seamless integration of a std::exception-derived class with lossless Unicode diagnostics?

Comment: No big deal, just use an encoding which uses bytes. IMO the bigger problem with `std:.exception` is that derived classes derive non-virtually from it. Due to that there's no way you could derive from your own base class, derived from `std::exception`, and, say, `std::out_of_range`.

Comment: @sbi:  True, but I dodge this problem by defining my heirarchy only in terms of `std::exception` directly.  I throw my own `std::exception`-derived exceptions and leave the other Standard-defined exceptions to the standard library.  Not an ideal solution, to be sure, but for my uses it is the best possible solution given the current state of the Standard.

Comment: Just noticed: Seems to be a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/618111/c-standard-exceptions-and-unicode/618150

Comment: *In Soviet Russia, exception throws you.*

Answer (score 36, accepted):

char* does not mean ASCII. You could use an 8 bit Unicode encoding like UTF-8. char could also be 16 bit or more, you could then use UTF-16.

Comment: The additional benefit with going the UTF-8 path is that STL et al exception text strings already are valid UTF-8. The problem is that it's a bit cumbersome to handle once you pass the 7-bit code points. At that point you'll either need custom output routines for UTF-8 or a conversion routine to an 8- or 16-bit code page all of which may or may not be something you want to do in your exception handler.

Comment: @Andreas: There's two problems when using `std::string` for UTF-8: One is that in UTF-8, there's a difference between the number of characters and the number of bytes in a string. The other is that it's very easy to confuse system-encoded strings (which every application will continue to need) and UTF-8-encoded ones, resulting in funny text to be shown to the users. I found it better to use, say, `std::basic_string<signed char>` for UTF-8-encoded strings. That eliminates at least the second problem, because it makes the compiler bark at you when you confuse the encoding.

Comment: How prevalent are system-encoded strings that use characters outside the ASCII subset?  If system-encoded strings can be restricted to the ASCII subset, then UTF-8 can be used without funny text.  As for string length, I like using `std::string` because I can get a byte count from it and can calculate the number of characters in O(n).  Basically, if you want the string to think in characters, you have to subclass `std::basic_string<signed char>`, change its iterator (and maybe demote it from being a random-access iterator), and add a byte count method.

Comment: @sbi: I think you misunderstood me, what I meant was that the text string returned from `what()` for the stdlib exceptions already are valid UTF-8 strings since they are ASCII and ASCII is a subset of UTF-8. Further I created one big "cumbersome problem" out of your two problems since all problems with UTF-8 begin when you move outside the ASCII subset. Speaking of solutions I quite like the accepted answer posted in the thread posted by `ybungalobill` below.

Answer (score 10):

Returning UTF-8 is an obvious choice. If the application that uses your exceptions uses a different multibyte encoding, it might have a hard time displaying the string though. (It can't know it's UTF-8, can it?)
On the other hand, for ISO-8859-* 8bit encodings (Western european, cyrillic, etc.) displaying a UTF-8 string will "just" display some gibberish and you (or your user) might be fine with that if you cannot disambiguate btw. a char* in the locale character set and UTF-8.

Personally I think only low level error messages should go into what() strings and personally I think these should be english anyway. (Maybe combined with some error number or whatnot.)

The worst problem I see with `what()` is that it is not uncommon to include some contextual details in the what() message, for example a *filename*. Filenames are *non* ASCII rather often, so you are left with no choice but to use UTF-8 as the `what()` encoding.

Note also that your exception class (that's derived from std::exception) can obviously provide any access methods you like and so it might make sense to add an explicit `what_utf8()` or `what_utf16()` or `what_iso8859_5()`.

*Edit: Regarding John's comment on how to return UTF-8:*

If you have a `const char* what()` function this function essentially returns a bunch of bytes. On a western european windows platform, these bytes would usually be encoded as [Win1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), but on a russian windows it might as well be [Win1251](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251).

What the bytes return signify depends on their encoding and their encoding depends on where they "came from" (and who is interpreting them). A string literal's encoding is defined at compile time, but at runtime it's still up to the application how to interpret these.

So, to have your exception return UTF-8 strings with `what()` (or `what_utf8()`) you have to make sure that:

- The input message to your exception has a well defined encoding
- You have a well defined encoding for the string member you use to hold the message.
- You appropriately convert the encoding when `what()`is called

Example:

```
struct MyExc : virtual public std::exception {
  MyExc(const char* msg)
  : exception(msg)
  { }
  std::string what_utf8() {
    return convert_iso8859_1_to_utf8( what() );
  }
};

// In a ISO-8859-1 encoded source file
const char* my_err_msg = "ISO-8859-1 ... äöüß ...";
...
throw MyExc(my_err_msg);
...
catch(MyExc const& e) {
  std::string iso8859_1_msg = e.what();
  std::string utf_msg = e.what_utf8();
...
```

The conversion could also be placed in the (overridden) what() member function of MyExc() *or* you could define the exception to take an already UTF-8 encoded string *or* you could convert (from an expected input encoding, maybe wchar_t/UTF-16) in the ctor.

Comment: "Returning UTF-8 is an obvious choice."  This seems to follow the arc of current thought.  Now the only question is, how do I return UTF-8? :)

Comment: @John Dibling:If the text of your messages is all in English and can be expressed in standard ASCII, you have already done enough because ASCII and the first 128 characters of UTF-8 are identical.  If you are using characters and an encoding above 127 you'll need to convert the encoding to UTF-8.  There must be a standard C++ library function to do that by now.  If not, libiconv can do the trick.

Comment: @JeremyP: we use ICU where I work to handle Unicode, certainly not perfect (C-interface...) but it does the work and handles the quircks of Unicode / Internationalization / Localization.

Comment: @Matthieu M: Thanks for that.  I was looking for a C compatible unicode library.  I could have used libiconv but it's licence is more restrictive.

Comment: @JeremyP: glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 4):

A const char* doesn't have to point to an ASCII string; it can be in a multi-byte encoding such as UTF-8. One option is to use `wcstombs()` and friends to convert wstrings to strings, but you may have to convert the result of `what()` back to wstring before printing. It also involves more copying and memory allocation than you may be comfortable with in an exception handler.

I usually just define my own base exception class, which uses wstring instead of string in the constructor and returns a const wstring& from `what()`. It's not that big of a deal. The lack of a standard one is a pretty big oversight.

Another valid opinion is that exception strings should never be presented to the user, so localizing them isn't necessary and so you don't have to worry about any of the above.

Comment: +1 Creating your own exception class is the most reasonable thing to do IMHO. If you catch a std::exception there is not much to do with it if the encoding is unknown (is it CP1252 or UTF-8 ?) If you have your own exception class, the problem is solved.

Answer (score 4):

The first question is what do you intend to do with the what() string?

Do you plan to log the information somewhere?

If so you should not be using the content of the what() string you should be using that string as a reference to look up the correct **local** specific logging message. So to me the content of the what() is not for logging purposes (or any form of display) it is a method of looking up the actual logging string (which can be any Unicode string).

Now; It can be us-full for the what() string to contain a human readable message for the developers to help in quick debugging (but for this highly readable polished text is not required). As result there is no reason to support anything more than ASCII. Obey the KISS principle.

Comment: In response to your questions.  I'd like to use the `what()` string in order to generate two levels of diagnostics.  The lower level is a developer- or technician-centric diagnostic that would be displayed in log files.  But at a higher level I'd like these strings to be used to construct a diagnostic that is actionable by a normal human being.  As you seem to imply, the `what()` return could simply be a lookup value in to a table of more humane messages, but some components of the string (or at least the exception) would need to be human-readable, such as " File blah.txt could not be found."

Comment: Another goal of mine is to keep `catch` blocks to a minimum.  Utopia would be to have a single `catch( const std::exception& ex )` block that catches everything, and that block would consume the `what()` string to produce both the technician- and human-level diagnostics.  Following this pattern, all of the data to construct both messages must be retrievable from the `what()` string.

Comment: Most local conversionlanguages take an input string and convert it to the local string via resources. So if you say the first part of the string upto a colon is used to look up local strings you can then do this:  `File could not be found: blah.txt`. The part `File could not be found:` can then be used to look up the local specific translation.

Comment: This underscores the basic flaw in the design of standard library exceptions: They should have been designed to be initialized with an integral constant instead of a `char const *`.

Answer (score 3):

It is better way to add unicode in error processing:

```
try
{
   // some code
}
catch (std::exception & ex)
{
    report_problem(ex.what())
}
```

And :

```
void report_problem(char const * const)
{
   // here we can convert char to wchar_t or do some more else
   // log it, save to file or message to user
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Standard doesn't specify what encoding is the string returned by what(), neither there is any defacto standard. I just encode it as UTF-8 and return from what(), in my projects. Of course there may be incompatibility with other libraries.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049947/should-utf-16-be-considered-harmful
for why UTF-8 is good choice.

Answer (score 1):

what() is generally not meant to display a message to a user. Among other things the text it returns is not localizable (even if it was Unicode). I'd just use what() to display something of value to you as the developer (like the source file and line number of the place where the exception was raised) and for that sort of text, ASCII is usually more than enough.

Comment: This is your opinion, and while I respect your opinion I don't share it.  Even if the `what()` output is only stored to a log file it is on some level "presented to the user" and needs to not be gibberish.

Comment: I am not saying it should be gibberish. I am saying that what() is not suitable to hold "international" text not because it can't hold Unicode (it can) but because it is not localizable.

Comment: Certainly the exception text may not need to be "internationalized" in the same way as text that the users normally see. But I can imagine times where a piece of Unicode text would still be very relevant and one would want it included with the exception. For example, a file name or path could have Unicode characters. Leaving that out would make the exception handling or logging less useful.

Comment: why can't you internationalize it ? Can't you access the local within `what` ?

Answer (score 0):

[The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)
by Joel Spolsky

Edit: Made CW, commenters may edit in why this link is relevant if they wish

Comment: -1 : I think adding a link (a great link, btw.) without any explanation on how this would relate to C++ exceptions does *nothing* to help *answer* the question. (It might help contextualize some encoding issues, but that what comments are for, no?) This is especially true if the OP actually needs to read the link.

Comment: Moreover, I've already read the link and it does not address my question.

Comment: To the contrary, I think this link provides *great* insight as to why using `char const*` has nothing to do with character encoding.

Comment: @Alexandre: but for a reader here on SO, there's no indication of *why* I should read this long article on an external site. As @Martin said, don't just post links, post a short summary and/or an explanation of *why* the link is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I created a template exception class `wexception` which takes `wstring` messages, stores them in a `string` as UTF-8, and converts them back into a `wstring` on retrieval. The code contains portions that are specific to MS C++: the `std::exception::exception(char*)` constructor and the functions `MultiByteToWideChar` and `WideCharToMultiByte` to convert to and from UTF-8, and `declspec(selectany)` which instructs the linker to create only one instance of a symbol that was defined multiple times. The template parameter can be any exception class that has a constructor which takes a `char*` parameter. The code doesn't use concepts so that it can compile under older language standards. There is room for improvement.

```
#include <Windows.h> // for UTF8 conversion functions and constants
#include <exception>
#include <string>

class wexception_base
{
public:
    static std::wstring wwhat(std::exception const& e)
    {
        return FromUtf8OrAnsi(e.what());
    }
    static bool IsUtf8Bom(char const* pmsg)
    {
        if (pmsg == nullptr)
            return false;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(m_Utf8Bom); ++i)
            if (pmsg[i] != m_Utf8Bom[i])
                return false;
        return true;
    }
    static std::wstring FromUtf8OrAnsi(char const* pmsg)
    {
        if (pmsg == nullptr)
            return {};
        size_t len = strlen(pmsg);
        bool const isUtf = IsUtf8Bom(pmsg);
        if (isUtf)
        {
            pmsg += sizeof(m_Utf8Bom);
            len -= sizeof(m_Utf8Bom);
            if (len == 0)
                return {}; // Quick exit for empty message
        }
        int const cp = isUtf ? CP_UTF8 : CP_ACP;
        size_t required = MultiByteToWideChar(cp, 0, pmsg, -1, nullptr, 0);
        _ASSERT(required > 0);
        _ASSERT(required <= INT_MAX);
        if (required > INT_MAX - 16) // why 16? probably 2 would be enough
            required = INT_MAX - 16;
        std::vector<wchar_t> buffer(required + 1);
        auto const used = MultiByteToWideChar(cp, 0, pmsg, -1, buffer.data(), static_cast<int>(buffer.size()));
        _ASSERT(used > 0);
        return buffer.data();
    }
    static std::string ToUtf8(wchar_t const* pmsg)
    {
        size_t required = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, pmsg, -1, nullptr, 0, nullptr, nullptr);
        _ASSERT(required > 0);
        _ASSERT(required <= INT_MAX);
        if (required >= INT_MAX)
            return {};
        std::vector<char> buffer(required + sizeof(m_Utf8Bom) + 1);
        memcpy_s(buffer.data(), required + 3, m_Utf8Bom, sizeof(m_Utf8Bom));
        auto const used = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, pmsg, -1, buffer.data() + sizeof(m_Utf8Bom), static_cast<int>(buffer.size()), nullptr, nullptr);
        _ASSERT(used > 0);
        return buffer.data();
    }
    static char m_Utf8Bom[3];
}; // class wexception_base
/*static*/ __declspec(selectany) char wexception_base::m_Utf8Bom[3] = {'\xEF', '\xBB', '\xBF'};

template<class BASE = std::exception>
class wexception : public BASE, public wexception_base
{
public:
    using BASE::BASE;
    template<typename... ARGS>
    wexception(wchar_t const* message, ARGS&&... args) : BASE(ToUtf8(message).c_str(), std::forward<ARGS>(args...))
    {
        static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<std::exception, BASE>, "BASE must be std::exception, or derived from std::exception");
    }
    template<typename... ARGS>
    wexception(std::wstring const& message, ARGS&&... args) : BASE(ToUtf8(message.c_str()).c_str(), std::forward<ARGS>(args)...)
    {
        static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<std::exception, BASE>, "BASE must be std::exception, or derived from std::exception");
    }
    template<typename... ARGS>
    wexception(std::string const& message, ARGS&&... args) : BASE(message.c_str(), std::forward<ARGS>(args)...)
    {
        static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<std::exception, BASE>, "BASE must be std::exception, or derived from std::exception");
    }
}; // template class wexception
```

You can throw and catch instances of `wexception` as any exception class. The catch clause looks like this:

```
    catch (std::exception const& e)
    {
        std::wstring msg = wexception<>::wwhat(e);
        std::wcerr << msg << std::endl;
        return; // or whatever
    }
```

The static function `wwhat` recognizes UTF-8 strings by the BOM, and assumes that strings that don't start with the BOM are ANSI coded. In any case, you get a `wstring` with the exception message.