# Is there a typical pattern for handling wide character strings in exceptions?

Tags: c++

Standard C++'s `std::exception::what()` returns a narrow character string. Therefore, if I want to put a wide character string message there, I can't.

Is there a common way/pattern/library of/for getting around this?

EDIT: To be clear, I could just write my own exception class and inherit from it -- but I'm curious if there's a more or less **standard** implementation of this. `boost::exception` seems to do most of what I was thinking of....

Comment: I was going to suggest re-encoding the string as UTF8 but given the situation in which it would be used, I'm glad I didn't!

Comment: Let me know if you find out. I am facing the same problem. One could in theory create a new base class for exceptions, but that makes all the catching ends really messy. Maybe a new class wexception : public std::exception, and do the magic inside, but I fear it could become very inefficient.

Comment: Possibly related: [Exceptions with Unicode what()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760731)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on this post [Exceptions with Unicode what()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760731/exceptions-with-unicode-what), I decided to do something like this:

```
class uexception : public std::exception {
public:
    uexception(LPCTSTR lpszMessage)
        : std::exception(TCharToUtf8(lpszMessage)) { }
};
```

Everywhere in my code base, I am assuming that `.what()` will return a string that is encoded in UTF-8. My conversion routines from UTF-8 to `TCHAR` will skip unrecognized UTF-8 sequences, and replace them with ?. That way, if `.what()` returns something that isn't valid UTF-8, it won't be an epic fail.

The code has not been compiled (later today - have to fix some other things first! :). I also apologize for the MFC-isms in there, but I think the message gets across anyway.

Comment: I'd use a character other than ? -- that way leads to massive security vulnerability fun. But +1 for a useful answer.

Comment: If you want to do it exactly right, use U+FFFD, the [Unicode replacement character](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/UFFF0.pdf) (a white ? in a black diamond) which is "used to replace an incoming character whose value is unknown or unrepresentable in Unicode."

Comment: Actually I am using the replacement character. (Just checked it :)

Comment: Accepting this answer because it looks like the one on which most effort was spent here, and because the answer to my question "does a typical pattern for this exist" appears to be "no".

Answer (score 4):

You can put anything there, but if third-party code expects a `const char*` from `what()`, you should return `const char*` from it.

For your code - just derive from `std::exception` and add `const wchar_t* wwhat()` method.

Answer (score 2):

Well, in Qt you get QString for strings, and that string is always in unicode. Not that you should go for Qt just for the sake of exceptions, but still :)

Comment: Well, Billy did ask for a library :)

Comment: Well, I'm using `std::wstring`... I already have a string in Unicode. What does that have to do with exceptions?