# C++ UNICODE and STL

Tags: c++, windows, unicode, stl, std

The Windows API seems big on `UNICODE`, you make a new project in Visual C++ and it sets it to `UNICODE` by default.
And me trying to be a good Windows programmer, I want to use `UNICODE`.

The problem is the C++ Standard Library and STL (such as *std::string*, or *std::runtime_error*) don't work well with `UNICODE` strings.
I can only pass a *std::string*, or a `char*` to *std::runtime_error*, and i'm pretty sure *std::string* doesn't support `UNICODE`.

So my question is, how should I use things such as *std::runtime_error*? Should I mix `UNICODE` and regular `ANSI`? (I think this is a bad idea...)
Just use `ANSI` in my whole project? (prefer not..) Or what?

Comment: They are exceptions, do you thik you need to internationalize them and really need unicode support for them?

Comment: You can mostly use `std::wstring` throughout.  `std::runtime_error` is an unfortunate exception (no pun intended!).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exceptions with Unicode what()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760731/exceptions-with-unicode-what)

Comment: @Björn Related but not a duplicate. The other question’s answers talk about using `char*` to store UTF-8. This doesn’t help here, since WinAPI uses `wchar_t` and UTF-16 so the answers cannot be adapted.

Comment: Ideally Windows would be updated to support, and start using by default, UTF-8 locales.

Comment: i prefer to have all my strings UTF-8 encoded, and convert to UTF-16LE for windows api's when needed ( using MultiByteToWideChar with CP_UTF8 as first argument )

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general you shouldn’t mix those two encodings. However, exception messages are something that is only of interest to the *developer* (e.g. in log files) and should never be shown to the user (but look at Jim’s comment for an important caveat).

So you are on the safe side if you use `UNICODE` for your whole user-faced interface and still use `std::exception` etc. behind the scenes for developer messages. There should be no need ever to convert between the two.

Furthermore, it’s a good trick to define a `typedef` for `UNICODE`-independent strings in C++:

```
typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR> tstring;
```

… and analogously define `tcout`, `tcin` etc. conditionally:

```
#ifdef UNICODE
    std::wostream& tcout = std::wcout;
    std::wostream& tcerr = std::wcerr;
    std::wostream& tclog = std::wclog;
    std::wistream& tcin = std::wcin;
#else
    std::ostream& tcout = std::cout;
    std::ostream& tcerr = std::cerr;
    std::ostream& tclog = std::clog;
    std::istream& tcin = std::cin;
#endif
```

Comment: I think there's an argument to be made that for cases like log files, you should use Unicode strings. Log files often mix user data with system data and user data may very likely include Unicode content. You could always assume ANSI exceptions, but a good exception might include a file path (for a file not found exception lets say) and that path could include Unicode characters).

Comment: Thumbed up for the typedef trick. But what if I want the error messages to be displayed to the user for them to report/identify problems? EDIT: Pretty much what Jim Lamb said.

Comment: @Josh This is unfortunately one of the few cases where you need to convert, e.g. using [`MultiByteToWideChar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Josh,

Please have a look at my answer here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/102205/should-utf-16-be-considered-harmful

There is growing number of engineers who believe std::string is just perfect for unicode on Windows, and is the right way to write portable and unicode-correct programs faster.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this (rather old now) article on CodeProject: [Upgrading an STL-based application to use Unicode](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4563/Upgrading-an-STL-based-application-to-use-Unicode). It covers the issues you're likely to hit if you're using the STL extensively. It shouldn't be that bad and, generally speaking, it's worth your while to use wide strings.

Comment: Hmm, this article is extremely outdated. For instance, it says that `wchar_t` is a typedef of `unsigned short` which causes overloading issues. This isn’t true on modern compilers.

Answer (score 0):

To work with Windows Unicode API, just use the wide string versions - wstring, etc. It won't help with `exception::what()`, but for that you can use UTF-8 encoding if you really need Unicode.